# Deploy RESTful server to CentOS

Tags: codeigniter, rest, basic-authentication

I am building a RESTful service with [Phil Sturgeon's library](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/working-with-restful-services-in-codeigniter-2/).
It works like a charm on localhost (windows 7, WAMP server). But when deploy on web server (CentOS), I cannot get the basic authentication. I've tried to modify REST_Controller.php at line 880:

```
protected function _check_login($username = '', $password = NULL)
{
    $this->response(array("username"=>$username, "password"=>$password));
    if (empty($username))
    {
        return FALSE;
    }
...
```

both username and password are null in the response.
Can anyone tell me how to fix this problem?
Thanks in advanced!

**[UPDATE]**
I found the answer here: http://www.sslcatacombnetworking.com/articles/http-authentication-php-cgi.html

Comment: can you answer this yourself and set as answered - stops it showing up in my feed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer here: http://www.sslcatacombnetworking.com/articles/http-authentication-php-cgi.html
[UPDATE]

**Step 1:**
Create a plain text file using a text editor such as Windows Notepad.

**Step 2:**
Add the following text...

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
     RewriteEngine on
     RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization},L]
</IfModule>
```

**Step 3:**
Save the file as a plain text file. Name the file ".htaccess"

**Step 4:**
Upload the .htaccess file in ASCII mode to your web space using an FTP application.

Step 5:
Add the following in your PHP script right before your user/pass check routine.

```
list($_SERVER['PHP_AUTH_USER'], $_SERVER['PHP_AUTH_PW']) = explode(':', base64_decode(substr($_SERVER['HTTP_AUTHORIZATION'], 6)));
```

Comment: Please write at least a couple of words about the solution. Once this link goes dead, no one will be able to use this answer in case they have a similar problem.